# Error compiling C# project with Protractor.dll as reference

Tags: protractor-net

We are developing a framework on top of Protractor/Selenium framework. Our projects are all C# signed projects. So, we need to reference signed Protractor and Selenium dlls.

I used the signed **WebDriver.dll** and **Webdriver.Support.dll** (version 2.46) from [here](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html).

But, when I compile my project, I am getting the below error -

"*The type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsDriver' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.46.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.*"

How can I address this error and get my code running?

Comment: I am thinking of getting the source code of protractor and recompile it to emit a signed assembly. Would this be a right approach?